# Dockerfile ubuntu only installs node version 4.2

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, docker

This dockerfile installs nodejs version 4.2 and I cant understand why. could someone please help me install node 9.2.  i've tried taking out the -- no install-recommends command to no avail.

adding more text her because stack would not let me post this even though it is a very simple question that I've looked on the web for quite some time about to no avail.adding more text her because stack would not let me post this even though it is a very simple question that I've looked on the web for quite some time about to no avail.

```
   FROM ubuntu:16.04
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl sudo
    RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
    RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && \
    apt-get install --yes build-essential
    RUN apt-get install --yes npm

    #VOLUME "/usr/local/app"

# Set up C++ dev env
RUN apt-get update && \
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
   apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib cmake wget -y  && \
   apt-get clean autoclean && \
   apt-get autoremove -y
   #wget -O /tmp/conan.deb -L https://github.com/conan-io/conan/releases/download/0.25.1/conan-ubuntu-64_0_25_1.deb && \
   #dpkg -i /tmp/conan.deb

#ADD ./scripts/cmake-build.sh /build.sh
#RUN chmod +x /build.sh
#RUN /build.sh


RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/app
WORKDIR /usr/local/app
COPY package.json /usr/local/app
RUN ["npm", "install"]
COPY . .


RUN echo "/usr/local/app/dm" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN echo "/usr/local/lib64" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/mythrift.conf
RUN ldconfig

RUN chmod +x dm/dm3
RUN ldd dm/dm3
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "dm/dm3"]
RUN ["chmod", "777", "policy"]
RUN ls -al .
RUN ["nodejs", "-v"]
CMD ["nodejs", "-v"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

Apparently it's important for the OP to run exactly this version of ubuntu. Here's a sample that builds on top of `FROM ubuntu:16.04`:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --reinstall ca-certificates curl build-essential \
&& curl -s https://nodejs.org/dist/v9.9.0/node-v9.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz \
-o node-v9.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz && tar xf node-v9.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz \
&& cd node-v9.9.0-linux-x64 && cp -r bin include lib share /usr/local \
&& rm -rf /node-v9.9.0-linux-x64.tar.xz /node-v9.9.0-linux-x64

CMD ["node", "-v"]
```

**Build**

```
docker build -t testing .
```

**Test**

```
docker run testing
v9.9.0
```

Note that this only takes care of the node related things and don't take into account all the other dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, this would work but i specifically need this version of ubuntu

Comment: May I ask why you need it?

Comment: Sure, I'm running an executable with thrift in my node app that was compiled with a Cpp compiler that is installed on a machine with this same version. I had to create a matching dockerfile in order to run the executable and load the compiler.

Comment: @JeremyNelson I have updated my answer. However, note that you have to add all the other stuff unrelated to node.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting node 4 is because `apt-get` only installs the default version of a package which will never be the cutting edge latest.

Whilst this issue is present in a Docker container, it is not specific to Docker as it will happen on any Ubuntu installation, both inside or outside of Docker.

To get the latest version you have 2 options.

(1) Install using a PPA:

```
cd ~
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x -o nodesource_setup.sh
sudo bash nodesource_setup.sh
sudo apt-get install nodejs
nodejs -v
```

(2) Install using Node Version Manager (nvm)

The latter is great because it lets you install multiple versions of Node and jump between them very quickly.

Here's a link to an amazing Digital Ocean article on this very topic:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Here's a link to NVM ... https://github.com/creationix/nvm